# Firebase: Is the structure I am using correct?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application that uses Firebase as a database.

I have always designed relational databases (MySQL) and I am not sure if I am designing the database I need well

In terms of MySQL, I have 3 tables that are related to each other.
The first table is called "Login", the second "Usuario" and the third "Fichada"

As for relationships, a "Login" is associated with a single "Usuario" (1: 1) and a "Login" can have many "Fichada" (0: *)

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEGd1.png)

What I need is to design that same structure but in the paradigm of non-relational databases.

Now i have something like that:

```
"Login":
    "atribute1" : value1
    "atribute2" : value2

    "Usuario": {
         "atribute3" : value3
         "atribute4" : value4
    }

    "Collection<Fichada>": {
         "atribute5" : atribute5
    }
```

I have a document called "Login", which inside has another document called "Usuario" and a collection of documents called "Fichada"

What I need is to know if this is correct. I am in doubt because when I enter the application, the user must enter their login information and at that time I do not need the information contained in "Fichada" at all. The question is that I don't know any way to get only the information I need at that time (When I get the Login document, I automatically get the "Usuario" and all of the "Fichada" documents).
In an alleged case of having 15.000.000 "Fichada", I do not want to bring them all, but as I bring from the Firebase is the Login object and not "Fichada" so, I can not filter or bring them later.

I am retrieving the Firebase information as follows:

```
Login login = new Login();
CollectionReference referenciaLogin = db.collection("login");

Query query = referenciaLogin.whereEqualTo("email", email);

List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentos = query.get().get().getDocuments();
login = documentos.get(0).toObject(Login.class);
login.setIdLogin(documentos.get(0).getId());
```

In this way, whenever I get the "Login" entity, I also get all the "Fichada", and I don't think it's optimal

Comment: There is not really such a thing as a "correct" data model for nosql type databases.  The model that satisfies all your intended queries is the correct one.  You might have to trade off size for flexibility in order to achieve this, which is totally normal.

Comment: I understand, however, the solutions that can occur to me to improve efficiency always draw towards the relational database model. Do you know if there is any way to obtain parts of documents programmatically (with the API provided by Firebase or something similar) and not the full document?

Comment: That is not possible.  Every query from a mobile client that reads a document will always read the entire document.

Comment: Too bad, it was my hope XD. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above structure is indeed correct, if you are highly concerned about the efficiency of retrieval, you can use one more level of indirection and design it like this:

```
"Login":
    "atribute1" : value1
    "atribute2" : value2
    "mapToUserIO" : value_3
    "mapToFichada" : value_4
```

and then have two more documents as follows:

```
"UserIO":
        "key": value_3
        "value":{
              "atribute3" : value3
              "atribute4" : value4
         }
```

That is, each value is a pair.

```
"Fichada":
        "key": value_4
        "value":"Collection<Fichada>": {
         "atribute5" : atribute5
    }
```

That is, the value of Fichada document will be a collection of Fichadas.

The only problem will be maintaining the unique key for the map, but you can use the username/id/unique identifier for the login table as a key for both. Hope that helps :)

Comment: This solution solves my "problem" of efficiency, but perhaps it is very similar to a relationship. I mean, in MySQL, we keep an ID to relate one entity to another. I think that one of the ideas of nonrelational databases is precisely to avoid that relationship. If I start using ID's it’s like I’m creating relationships between the documents, isn't it?

Comment: True, but the constraint of having a fixed data type is absent, so extending the document of UserIO/Fichada whenever you like is possible, which as per me is one of the biggest advantages of a NoSQL database. If you don't really want to have a map, it will be difficult to extract part of the document, because performance/flexibility trade-off is always there :)

Comment: I see. I guess I will use this solution since efficiency is important to me but both documents must be related. Thanks for the reply :)